# 3d perspective looks unnatural in libgdx

Tags: 3d, libgdx, render, perspectivecamera

when I render my 3d model using the PerspectiveCamera, the perspective looks unnatural. The side of the model facing the camera is shown much largeer then the opposite side.

How can I adjust it?

here is a screenshot:

[image: http://imageshack.com/a/img713/1599/hl21.png]

Comment: Have you expicitly set `fieldOfView` parameter while creating perspective camera ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move your camera further back.  That should compensate